# Django Paginator uses locale output

Tags: python, django

When I use Django Paginator with `en` locale, then page number is `3,987` instead of `3987`.

How can I get rid of thousand separator and show "raw" numbers, because link appears to be broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [unlocalize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/formatting/#unlocalize) filter which forces a single value to be printed without localization:

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ value|unlocalize }}
```